# Skip a super class when calling a super method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may seem strange, but I would like to do the following:

Class A

```
- (void)someMethod;
```

Class B : A

```
- (void)someMethod; // overrides
```

Class C : B

```
- (void)someMethod; // overrides
```

In class C, I would like to override a method present in the two super classes, but call only Class A's method on a [super methodName] call.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  [super someMethod];  // but I want to call class A, not B
}
```

Possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// in Class C:
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)someMethod
{
    // I want to call class A's implementation of this method

    IMP method = class_getMethodImplementation([ClassA class], _cmd);

    method(self, _cmd);

}
```

Comment: @Javy -- If you do that, definitely comment it well.

Comment: Does this approach work with a method that returns something? I'd like to return a CGSize from super super.

Comment: Can we pass an argument along with it ? Please add return type and with argument if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do a hacky solution whereby you pass an integer parameter into the method which is decremented on each super call, such that each method implementation just calls its superclass method until finally you reach 0, then you actually execute the method. It's sort of like a weird form of recursion.

Comment: Yup, I'd considered something like that, but I'm hoping for a more encapsulated solution.  I don't know if it's possible though.  =)